# SENSOR_SERVICE == null?

Tags: android

The last couple of days I've been trying to find the reason why the call [1] gives me on some devices null value (I'm using Bugsense in my project and several phones which includes those [2] have raported the null value). Any ideas what could be the problem???

[1]

```
sensorManager = 
    (SensorManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    // it's within the Activity's onCreate
```

[2] Woxter Tablet PC 75, QW TB-1010, HTC Explorer A310e, ThL V7 and more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand (reference [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.String))) this method can return null value when the service isn't implemented at a given device.

> Note: When implementing this method, keep in mind that new services
> can be added on newer Android releases, so if you're looking for just
> the explicit names mentioned above, make sure to return null when you
> don't recognize the name — if you throw a RuntimeException exception
> instead, you're app might break on new Android releases.